# How do I override my Vagrantfile's synced_folder type per provider?

Tags: vagrantfile

I have a Vagrantfile with more than one provider, and they can't use the same synced_folder types. How do I change all the synced_folder types in the per-provider section? I would like to avoid repeating the synced_folder definitions for each provider.

```
  config.vm.synced_folder "prog", "/home/vagrant/prog", type: "virtualbox"
  # more synced folders

  config.vm.provider "docker" do |docker, override|
    override.vm.box = nil
    docker.build_dir = "."

    # change all synced_folder types here?
```

Answer (score 0):

`config.vm.synced_folder` is a method call that appends to a `@__synced_folders` data structure inside the VM configuration object.

One way to do it might be to leave the type unset in the `synced_folder` declaration, and then set the `allowed_synced_folder_types` an array of the desired type for each provider. Another way might be to declare a local array of `synced_folder` arguments, looping over it in each provider configuration to pass the desired type to `synced_folder`.

`override.vm.allowed_synced_folder_types = [:virtualbox, :rsync]`